# Add Logo in Actionbar using extends Activity in the main_activity

Tags: java, android, xml

how can I add a logo in the actionbar. My main_activity extends Activity.
 I know the way if I extend ActionBarActivity, but I have to do it with the Activity.

[image: Picture]

Comment: a) Why do you HAVE TO use plain Activity? b) You can add appcompat functionality to regular Activity by using [AppCompatDelegate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This code . You can custom icon (`actionbar_logo`).

```xml
<style name="MyTheme_ActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="icon">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
</style>
```

Import this class .

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActivityBarActivity {

      ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
      mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
  }
```

Comment: this is my style: <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>                                                                                                     I can't use getSupportActionBar(); the main_activity extends Activity

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and it is working.
activity_main.xml

---

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#f00fcd">
    </android.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

---

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setActionBar(toolbar);
        // setActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. app is crashing.